# HTML list elements won't list horizontally?

Tags: html, menu, html-lists

Basically I'm trying to make a web coding tutorial site (awesome that i cant do it myself right). For the life of me I can't figure out why my list items wont list horizontally instead of vertically.

[See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/QUjXh/)

Comment: +1 for posting a fiddle, -1 for the blind leading the blind.  Please develop more expertise before publishing tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have a `width: 100px` set on your `#menu` selector, which is crunching that box down to only allow for one element per line. [Just remove it.](http://jsfiddle.net/pE2Y4/)

Comment: Thanks. cant believe it was so simple -_-

Answer (score 0):

Fixed here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QUjXh/8/)

```
#menu {
    width: 600px;                   <-- changed from 100px to 400px
    height: 15px;
    position: relative;
    color: #999999;
    margin: 0px auto;
    float:left;                       <-- new
}
```

Answer was updated. The container element should be wide enough to accomodate all element horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

change the menu width 100px in to 100% it's work

here my output:
  http://jsfiddle.net/srinivasan/XmhqW/